Comparing the value of convex linear homogeneous functions of added random variables
I got stuck by proof and was wondering if the following argument might be true.
Consider random variables $x(\omega)$, $y(\omega)$, $z(\omega)$, $x'(\omega)$, $y'(\omega)$, and $z'(\omega)$. All random variables are always positive. We further have $E[x(\omega)]=E[x'(\omega)]$, $E[y(\omega)]=E[y'(\omega)]$, and $E[z(\omega)]=E[z'(\omega)]$
For each convex linear homogeneous function $g$, we have
\begin{equation}
E\{g[x(\omega),y(\omega)]\}\geq E\{g[x'(\omega),y'(\omega)]\},
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
E\{g[x(\omega),z(\omega)]\}\geq E\{g[x'(\omega),z'(\omega)]\}.
\end{equation}
Is it true that for each $\alpha\in(0,1)$ and each convex linear homogeneous function $g$,
we have
\begin{equation}
E\{g[x(\omega),u(\omega)]\}\geq E\{g[x'(\omega),u'(\omega)]\},
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
u(\omega)=\alpha y(\omega)+(1-\alpha)z(\omega),
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u'(\omega)=\alpha y'(\omega)+(1-\alpha)z'(\omega).
\end{equation}
Thank you very much :)

What means ``convex linear homogeneous''? It seems that this condition implies that $g$ is linear.
